# how deploy qwik js on shared hosting?

Tags: node.js, deployment, qwik, qwikjs

I cannot deploy Qwik js project on shared hosting, can you share how to resolve it?

Deploy qwik js on shared hosting. vercel or nelify deploy ok. but when I'll try to hosting in custom server i cant understand how to deploy on live server

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.